# Detect usb Modem Ports With IMEI No

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have deployed several usb modems (mostly huawei) which are used as SMS agents in an SMS server setup.

The problem is that sometimes when a reboot happens, some devices are re-assigned to other COM port slots. It causes problems since the program can no longer access the serial port/COM port. It needs to be reassigned manually.

My solution is to save IMEI numbers of all devices in database. When my program run it gets IMEI number from database and tries to detect all three ports with same IMEI number that I select.

My question is how to detect usb ports with IMEI number?

Answer (score 0):

I would try using WMI query first. search for WMI and Com Ports will give clues to enumerate ports and get their properties

```
  ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

                foreach (ManagementObject obj in searcher.Get())
                {

                 // Enumerate object properties  here
                  }
```

Comment: in ManagementObjectSearcher it get imei no

Comment: @user3377728 You won't get IMEI, but you will get what COM ports are used. The issue is if the 3 modems are identical how to tell them apart (if it matters). You could open the port, send some type of query to the modem that gets IMEI and then you will know which one you have and can act accordingly.